# importing ngx-highlight.js themes cause mime type error

Tags: angular, highlightjs

I just added `ngx-highlight.js` to my Angular project and am having some difficulty figuring out how to get it set up.  I've been following [these instructions](https://ngx-highlight.netlify.app/) and looking at [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-highlightjs?file=src%2Fmain.ts) to figure out how to set everything up.  So far my code looks like this

**main.ts**

```
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(SITEROUTES),
    provideAnimations(),
    {
      provide: HIGHLIGHT_OPTIONS,
      useValue: {
        coreLibraryLoader: () => import('highlight.js/lib/core'),
        lineNumbersLoader: () => import('ngx-highlightjs/line-numbers'),
        languages: {
          css: () => import('highlight.js/lib/languages/css')
        },
        themePath: 'node_modules/highlight.js/styles/a11y-dark.css'
      }
    }
  ]
};


bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

**GettingStartedComponent**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterLink } from '@angular/router';
import{ HighlightModule, HighlightLoader } from 'ngx-highlightjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-getting-started-page',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterLink, HighlightModule],
  templateUrl: './getting-started-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./getting-started-page.component.css']
})

export class GettingStartedPageComponent {

  code: string =
  `.demoClass{
  display: grid;
  place-self: center;
}
  
  `;

  constructor(){}

}
```

**Template**

```
<pre>
  <code
    [highlight]="code"
    [languages]="['css']"
    [lineNumbers]="true"
  >

  </code>
</pre>
```

When I added `themePath: 'node_modules/highlight.js/styles/a11y-dark.css'` in my `main.ts` file I got the following error

> Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:4200/node_modules/highlight.js/styles/a11y-dark.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

I noticed in the stackblitz example that they imported a module into the constructor so I added this to mine

```
constructor(private hljsLoader: HighlightLoader){
  this.hljsLoader.setTheme('node_modules/highlight.js/styles/a11y-dark.css');
}
```

That created the same error so I figured maybe the path was wrong and added `../../../` until I got up to the root folder so it would follow the proper path and that didn't make any difference.
I tried importing it into my component's stylesheet like this

```
@import url('../../../../../node_modules/highlight.js/styles/a11y-dark.css');
```

This made the background of of the `<pre>` tag a charcoal gray but all the text was white rather than being color coded, there also wasn't any margin between the text and the line numbers.  I also tried adding the stylesheet for the theme to my `angular.json` file in both the style tags present however this makes no difference.  What am I doing wrong?

***UPDATE***

So I discovered adding the theme to my `angular.json` file makes it work after re-running `ng serve` however the column for the line numbers still doesn't look right as you can see bellow.

[image: in my project] [image: in the stackblitz demo]

See how the second one has a nice column with a border and a little margin between the border and the text while in the first one the text is crammed right next to the numbers?  How do I fix this?  Even though the text styling now works I still get the MIME type error in the console as well.  What am I missing?